# Launch a shell command with in a python script, wait for the termination and return to the script

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, os.execl

I have a python script that has to launch a shell command for every file in a dir:

```
import os

files = os.listdir(".")
for f in files:
    os.execlp("myscript", "myscript", f)
```

This works fine for the first file, but after the "myscript" command has ended, the execution stops and does not come back to the python script.

How can I do this? Do I have to `fork()` before `calling os.execlp()`?

Comment: [`returncode = subprocess.call(['myscript', f])`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5184921/4279)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

> subprocess: The `subprocess` module
>   allows you to spawn new processes,
>   connect to their input/output/error
>   pipes, and obtain their return codes.

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Usage:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print process.returncode
```

Comment: I think as the accepted answer, this should contain at least the same amount of detail as @Harley.

This is more of a personal request, but I think the newer docs present the information better. Could you link to the 2.7 version of  the documentation instead?

Comment: The newer version of the documentation is located at http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html .

Comment: remove stdout=PIPE it might hang the script if the child program produces enough output (around 65KB on Linux). `shell=True` is unnecessary.

Comment: Without shell=True it raises an exception on python 2.7...   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 66):

You can use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).  There's a few ways to do it:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['/run/myscript', '--arg', 'value']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in p.stdout:
    print line
p.wait()
print p.returncode
```

Or, if you don't care what the external program actually does:

```
cmd = ['/run/myscript', '--arg', 'value']
subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait()
```

Comment: `for line in p.stdout:` might delay the output of a line due to read-ahead. You could use `for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''): print line,` (note: comma at the end). Remove stdout=PIPE in the second example; it might hang the script. Or just use `subprocess.call()` if you don't need an exception for non-zero returned code

Comment: @HarleyHolcombe i tried your solution via `subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/sleep 20").wait()`, which didn't work (`FileNotFoundError:`), to make it work I had to separate the command into substrings  and put them into a list `subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/sleep", "20"]).wait()` why is that necessary?

Answer (score 13):

The subprocess module has come along way since 2008.  In particular [`check_call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) and [`check_output`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) make simple subprocess stuff even easier.  The `check_*` family of functions are nice it that they raise an exception if something goes wrong.

```
import os
import subprocess

files = os.listdir('.')
for f in files:
   subprocess.check_call( [ 'myscript', f ] )
```

Any output generated by `myscript` will display as though your process produced the output (technically `myscript` and your python script share the same stdout).  There are a couple of ways to avoid this.

- `check_call( [ 'myscript', f ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE )`
  The stdout will be supressed (beware if `myscript` produces more that 4k of output).  stderr will still be shown unless you add the option `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`.
- `check_output( [ 'myscript', f ] )`
  `check_output` returns the stdout as a string so it isnt shown.  stderr is still shown unless you add the option `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

Comment: @Luke Stanley: your question is unclear, but I'll give it a shot.  The `subprocess.check_*` functions makes calling external binaries easier than manually using `subprocess.Popen`.  In particular you never need to deal with `wait()`, `communicate()`, `return_code`, etc.  You also don't need to worry about gotchas like the dangling pipe stalling the executable.  When it comes to _interacting_ with an external binary the `check_*` functions aren't tremendously helpful, but for most use cases the result is shorter and less error prone, aka easier.

Comment: you could use `subprocess.DEVNULL` or `open(os.devnull, 'r+b')` to ignore input/output instead of subprocess.PIPE to avoid possible dead-lock

Answer (score 7):

The `os.exec*()` functions *replace* the current programm with the new one. When this programm ends so does your process. You probably want `os.system()`.

Comment: os.system() is very problematic in terms of security, to the point where many C libraries just remove this standard C function outright. subprocess.Popen() with shell=False should be used instead

Answer (score 3):

use spawn

```
import os
os.spawnlp(os.P_WAIT, 'cp', 'cp', 'index.html', '/dev/null')
```

Answer (score 2):

I use os.system

```
import os
os.system("pdftoppm -png {} {}".format(path2pdf, os.path.join(tmpdirname, "temp")))
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me fine!

`shell_command = "ls -l"
subprocess.call(shell_command.split())`