# Connect to a samba share with python in a platform independent manner?

Tags: python, abstraction, samba

Is there an abstraction that will allow me to connect to a samba share in python regardless of my platform?

**More information**

I do not want to mount a share. I simply want to upload files to a share, such as smbclient's put.

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pysmb seems to do this:
https://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/projects/pysmb (edited with new link)

Comment: That link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232420/how-to-mount-a-network-directory-using-python), I would use `subprocess` to execute a `mount` command in Unix-y systems (most all of them save windows) -- and `mountvol` on windows, which that SO question doesn't mention.  It's a tiny difference in the string to pass to `subprocess`, easy to encapsulate in a tiny function, which may be the reason I don't think there's any "third party solution" to this issue -- it's just too small an issue;-).

If you don't want to *mount* the filesystem, nosklo (a frequent SO poster) has made available a [package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySmbClient/0.1.2) to access the filesystem directly, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: nosklo's package depends on smbclient which is unavailable on Windows.