# Using python to run another program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a program that I run from the command line that looks like this:

`$ program a.txt b.txt`

The program requires two text files as arguments. I am trying to write a Python 3.2 script to run the above program. How can I do this? Currently, I am trying to use the `subprocess` module like this:

```
import subprocess

with open("a.txt", mode="r") as file_1:
    with open("b.txt", mode="r") as file_2:
        cmd = ['/Users/me/src/program', file_1, file_2]
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        for line in process.stdout:
            print(line)
```

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python) and the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325463/launch-a-shell-command-with-in-a-python-script-wait-for-the-termination-and-retu), which seem to describe similar solutions to my problem. Unfortunately, after reading these posts, I still can't seem to make my Python code run my program.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen` expects an array of strings. Two of the items in that array are file handles. You need to pass the actual file *name* to the program you're trying to run.

```
cmd = ['/Users/me/src/program', 'a.txt', 'b.txt']
```

You can get rid of the `with open(...) as ...` lines completely.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I somehow missed that `subprocess.Popen()` requires strings not file handles. Your solution worked like a charm!

Answer (score 28):

Look at [@Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945466/using-python-to-run-another-program/6945501#6945501), and also:

Subprocess doesn't wait for command to finish, so you should use `wait` method.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
for line in process.stdout:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the `wait` method - I was not aware of this.

Comment: If you want lines while it's still running, see my answer.

Answer (score 13):

Depending on your requirements, `os.system(cmdline)` might be the simples solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `subprocess.wait()` with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` is not recommended.

```
with subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    print(proc.stdout.read())
```

You don't have to call `subprocess.wait()`. This will print realtime stdout of `proc` and parent process will wait the termination of `proc`.

Check these urls for more information.

- https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects
- https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor