# execute python script from another file (after reaching end of file)

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I am trying to execute script (say, main.py) from another file (say, test.py), I don't want to call any function of main, instead i want to start executing the file from `if __name__=="__main__":`

Example:
test.py

```
def funA():
    ....
def funB():
    ....
#the last function of file
def funC():
    #here i want to start executing main.py without calling any function.
```

main.py

```
def fun_x(arg1):
    #do something

if __name__ == "__main__":   #execution starts here
     arg1=10
     x(arg1)
```

Is it possible to call the main directly like this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using python to run another program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945466/using-python-to-run-another-program)

Comment: You could execute `main.py` as a child process, is that what you mean?

Comment: Why not omit the `__name__ == "__main__"`, and import the main.py in funcC()? What's the point in having this check if main.py is not supposed to be `__main__`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the script "like a user would do" with The [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.