# Execute command with delay using subprocess

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute this command from a python script using subprocess: `sleep 10 && sudo /etc/init.d/tractor-blade restart &`

I want the python script to finish (return code 0). Then, 10 seconds later I wish the command to get executed.

This is what I have:

```
import sys, subprocess
command = ['sleep', '10', '&&', 'sudo', '/etc/init.d/tractor-blade', 'restart' '&']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

# Catch stdout
sys.stdout.flush()
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print(">>> " + line.rstrip())
```

But this is what happens:

```
>>> sleep: invalid time interval `&&'
>>> sleep: invalid time interval `sudo'
>>> sleep: invalid time interval `/etc/init.d/tractor-blade'
>>> sleep: invalid time interval `restart'
>>> sleep: invalid time interval `&'
>>> Try `sleep --help' for more information.
```

I am guessing my formatting is wrong?

I need to make the python script complete before the command is being executed, which is why I am trying to add a delay to the command. My sudoers allows for this `tractor-blade' to get executed with NOPASSWD, thus does not require a password.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch a shell command with in a python script, wait for the termination and return to the script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325463/launch-a-shell-command-with-in-a-python-script-wait-for-the-termination-and-ret)

Comment: I do NOT want to wait for termination. I want to delay the execution of the command and exit the python script. Then I want the command to get executed, 10 seconds after the python script has exited.

Comment: Yes, it is still the same problem.  You do NOT need to `wait`.  All you need is `shell = True`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is because subprocess can work in two modes: either you `fork()` the process specified by the tuple passed as argument, or you execute the string with a shell. The difference is the `shell` argument. So what you might want to do is:

```
command = "sleep 10 && sudo /etc/init.d/tractor-blade restart"
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

or:

```
time.sleep(10)
command = ['sudo', '/etc/init.d/tractor-blade', 'restart' '&']
subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> *The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.*

Answer (score 0):

The way the API works is, the first element in `command` is the program that `subprocess.Popen` will invoke. And the rest of that list is parsed and then fed into that program as arguments. By default, they are not parsed as a shell command.