# How to do a blocking system call in python (and get its result as a string)

Tags: python

How do I make a blocking operating system call in python?

For example get the output of the linux "date" command.

And put its string output result into a string variable.

---

Dear Stackoverflow.

What is unclear about "operating system call"

What is unclear about "blocking"

I suspect the people who "close" do not even read the question.

Is there a procedure for unblocking questions?

Comment: what is not clear about the question? please remove the downvotes.

Comment: @magic-sudo I am a downvote nazi myself, but not for fun

Comment: @SHernandez -- you get my upvote! This is a fine question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325463/launch-a-shell-command-with-in-a-python-script-wait-for-the-termination-and-ret third result for *python how to run external command and wait for return*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the output of a command, use `check_output`, which has the advantage over `Popen` that it raises an exception if the command fails :

```
from subprocess import check_output
output = check_output(["date"])
```

(*I assumed that you're not talking about real [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).*)

Comment: if I want a real system call I call my mother lol

Comment: very interesting, check_output seems like a convenience wrapper isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, see the [subprocess](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L588) module. It's convenient though ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['date'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

The first argument to Popen is the list of command line arguments you'd like executed. The PIPE arguments which follow instruct python to capture the output of the command. `communicate()` waits for the command to complete and returns the stdout and stderr of the process as strings. After execution, the `stdout` variable will contain the text from the subprocess. Note that there are a few caveats to this pattern (particularly with large amounts of output). You can learn more here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: This is a very good answer but F.X.'s way is more convenient and also handles errors and exceptions nice. Will probably have to accept his

Comment: @SHernandez --  That's true, but it is not available in all versions of python. The code I work with generally requires the lowest common denominator. So, I generally use the less-convenient approach and error catch where needed. The very best solution will depend upon your use case.

Comment: It should be noted that stdout and stderr in the last line are bytestrings with a newline at the end. But the same name parameters to the function calls are operating system pipe objects, just to prevent confusion

Answer (score 1):

You can call:

```
import os

os.system('date')
```

Comment: this is nice but misses the "string result" part. result is integer.

Comment: The simple and age-old way of doing it. Still works like a charm.