# Embed filename using python-gnupg

Tags: python, gnupg

I'm able to embed the original filename using python-gnupg when encrypting a file using below:

```
filename = 'test.tim'
with open(filename, 'rb) as fh:
    status = gpg.encrypt_file(fh, recipients='somerecipient', output='test.tim.gpg',\
        sign='somesignature', extra_args=['--set-filename', os.path.basename(filename)])
```

This can be verified by using gpg from the command line:

> $ gpg2 --list-packets test.tim.gpg | grep name

I am however unable to preserve the original filename ***when decrypting the file:***

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as fh:
    status = gpg.decrypt_file(fh, extra_args['--use-embedded-filename'])
```

I am aware about the output parameter (which specifies the filename to save contents to) in the decrypt_file function, but i want to preserve the original filename (which i won't always know)

It seems the decrypt_file function always passes the --decrypt flag to gpg which always ouputs the contents to stdout (unless used in conjunction with output parameter) as in:

> $ gpg --decrypt --use-embedded-filename test.tim.gpg

Below command will decrypt and save output to original filename:

> $ gpg --use-embedded-filename test.tim.gpg

Any ideas?

Tim

Answer (score 1):

The functionality to do what you want doesn't exist in [the original python-gnupg](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/python-gnupg).

There's a modified version [here](https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg) by isislovecruft (which is what you get if you `pip install gnupg`) that adds support for `--list-packets` with `gpg.listpackets` but still doesn't support `--use-embeded-file-name`

So my approach, if I were to insist on using python only, would probably be to start with isislovecruft's version and then subclass GPG like this:

```
import gnupg
import os

GPGBINARY = os.environ.get('GPGBINARY', 'gpg')
hd = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'keys')

class myGPG(gnupg.GPG):

    def decrypt_file_original_name(self, file, always_trust=False, passphrase=None, extra_args=None):
        args = ["--use-embedded-filename"]
        output = calculate_the_file_name_using_list_packets()
        self.set_output_without_confirmation(args, output)
        if always_trust:  # pragma: no cover
            args.append("--always-trust")
        if extra_args:
            args.extend(extra_args)
        result = self.result_map['crypt'](self)
        self._handle_io(args, file, result, passphrase, binary=True)
        # logger.debug('decrypt result: %r', result.data)
        return result

gpg = myGPG(gnupghome=hd, gpgbinary=GPGBINARY)
```

Bear in mind, at this point it is almost certainly *much* easier to just use [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325463/launch-a-shell-command-with-in-a-python-script-wait-for-the-termination-and-ret) and run the gpg binary directly from the shell, especially as you don't care about the output.

Anyway, I got this far and have run out of time for now, so I leave implementing `calculate_the_file_name_using_list_packets` up to you, if you choose to go the 'pure python' route. Hopefully it is a bit easier now you have `gpg.list-packets`. Good luck!